Setting (nlohmann::json) options for CMake projects added with find_package
I am using the excellent nlohmann::json library. I can see that it has an option for disabling implicit conversion which is recommended.
First I tried to set this option via:
set(JSON_ImplicitConversions OFF)
find_package(nlohmann_json 3.10.3 REQUIRED)

But that did not seem to have any effect. I then tried using fetch_content:
set(JSON_ImplicitConversions OFF)
FetchContent_Declare(json
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/nlohmann/json
    GIT_TAG v3.11.3
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(json)

And this gave the required effect. I much prefer the find_package. Am I using it wrong? Is it not possible to set options in this way with find_package?

JSON_ImplicitConversions is the option used when build the library. find_package locates the library which is already built and installed. So setting build options for find_package is useless.
That build option affects on the setting macro JSON_USE_IMPLICIT_CONVERSIONS for the consumer of the library. You may set this macro manually for the imported target, created by find_package:
find_package(nlohmann_json 3.10.3 REQUIRED)

# For the case the macro is already set in the target's compile definitions
# we need to remove that setting. Otherwise it will conflict with our one.

# Extract current value of the property (as list)
get_target_property(prop_value nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
# Remove unneeded elements
list(FILTER prop_value EXCLUDE REGEX "JSON_USE_IMPLICIT_CONVERSIONS")
# Put resulting list back to the property
set_property(TARGET nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json PROPERTY INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ${prop_value})
 
target_compile_definitions(nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json INTERFACE
  JSON_USE_IMPLICIT_CONVERSIONS=0
)


Clear and to the point. Thank you.

There still seems to be an issue with this approach. Looking at my compile_commands.json I can see that this has been overwritten:
-DJSON_USE_IMPLICIT_CONVERSIONS=0 -DJSON_USE_IMPLICIT_CONVERSIONS=1
I.e., the definitions has been appended somehow, with the default setting, making my definition useless.

I've removed it as the accepted answer for now, since the solution does not seem to work (although the reason why mine doesn't work is valid!)

It occurs that in older versions of nlohmann_json project they set the macro JSON_USE_IMPLICIT_CONVERSIONS in any case, not only for the value 0. I added the code which removes this setting before adding our macro definition.

Great help! Just verified that it works. Thanks again.
